# IntelliJ_SBT_guava 28.1-jre version dependencies is not getting resolved with my build.sbt

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, guava

I am working with IntelliJ SBT on windows. For some reasons guava 28.1-jre version dependencies is not resolved with my build.sbt

[image]

To resolve the issue can i download the specific jar from below link to my desktop location? If yes then which file I have to to download. There are plenty of them.

```
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-jre/
```

[image]

Once downloaded to local machine,can i add dependencies as shown in below screenshot via option (CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to add resolvers in your `build.sbt` file

```
resolvers ++= Seq("guava" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava")
```

add below to your plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.0.3")
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll take a look at your failure console, you'll see that the reason it didn't fetch the jar, is that the pom file is missing. Navigating to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/28.1-jre confirms that.
You can find that jar at [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/28.1-jre).
In order to import that jar from maven all you need to do is to add the following into your sbt file:

```
resolvers += "guava" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "28.1-jre"
)
```

I always suggest to look for the dependencies at maven/[sonatype](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/28.1-jre/bundle) before looking anywhere else, because they force having all necessary files in order to pull the dependency.

Comment: We have done as suggested ,but it is giving the same issue."Unkown artifact. Not resolved or indexed"

Comment: Try to clean your cache. Which version of intellij are you using? Try to upgrade it.